# VTK package not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi am trying to download a **VTK package** which is a dependency for my other package. I tried to access the repository **https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/point_cloud_perception/trunk/vtk** but is gives me the error that the **URL can't be found on my sever.** Also, when i click the link, it says that the repository cant be accessed on my sever . Can you please help me as to how to get the VTK package. Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11424/vtk-package-not-found/) by [siddhu723](https://answers.ros.org/users/1166/siddhu723/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-10-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The old [point_cloud_perception](http://www.ros.org/wiki/point_cloud_perception) stack is *deprecated*.

The current [perception_pcl](http://www.ros.org/wiki/perception_pcl) stack no longer contains a VTK stack. Instead, it has a `rosdep` dependency on the system `libvtk` version.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-04**:
That should work.

**Comment by [siddhu723](https://answers.ros.org/users/1166/siddhu723/) on 2011-10-05**:
Is it enough if i just get the perception_pcl package then ?